# Regex to allow for anystring in url

Tags: regex

```
const profileActive = location.pathname && location.pathname.match(/^\/app\/profile/) ? "profileActive" : "";
```

My case need to match:

```
/app/profile/ANYTHINGHERE/report
```

At the moment it matches just:

```
/app/profile/
```

Any help to express a match anything expression between  /   /

Thanks

Comment: Use: `match(/^\/app\/profile/.+/report$/)`

Comment: Try `/^\/app\/profile.*\/report$/` or `/^\/app\/profile(?:\/.*)?\/report$/`

Comment: Just FYI: `/^\/app\/profile/.+/report$/` would not match `/app/profile/report`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either

```
/^\/app\/profile(?:\/.*)?\/report$/
```

See [this **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/InM8EP/1)

Or, if there should only be 1 subpart in between:

```
/^\/app\/profile(?:\/[^\/]+)?\/report$/
```

See [this **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/InM8EP/3).

The `(?:\/[^\/]+)?` will match an optional sequence of `/` and 1+ chars other than `/` while `(?:\/.*)?` will match an optional sequence of a `/` followed with any 0+ chars.